# With scss @extend pseudo selected CSS

Tags: css, sass

One can do `@extend .foo` but apparently not `@extend .foo:focus`.

I'm dealing with a 3rd party component which adds it's own `focused` class when it considers it is focused. Using `@extend` to apply Bootstrap styles works fine, but because the 3rd party component does not get a `:focus` the `.form-control:focus` is never matched.

My SCSS in principal would be:

```
.thirdparty {
  @extend .form-control;
}
.thirdparty.thirdparty-focused {
  @extend .form-control:focus;
}
```

`@extend .form-control:focus;` does not compile however.

Currently I can't figure out how to do this without copying the `.form-control:focus` CSS into `.thirdparty.thirdparty-focused`, which is obviously rather unideal.

Is some sort of `@extend .form-control:focus;` equivalent possible, and if not, any suggestions better than copying N lines of CSS to match the rest of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

`@extend .form-control:focus` will act as a selector, specifically looking for a rule named `.form-control:focus`. Here is an [illustration](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/vYGPPpX).

The best solution to your problem would be to outsource the `:focus` pseudo-selector of the original Bootstrap class, using the `%`-selector, and then re-extend it into it - so that you could call it seperately.

```
%focus {
  color: #2196f3;
}

.base {
  color: #000;
  
  &:focus {
    @extend %focus;
  }
}

div {
  @extend .base;
  
  &.focus {
    @extend %focus;
  }
}

// Other Bootstrap components can still call `@extend .base;`
```

This will compile to:

```
.base:focus, div:focus, div.focus {
  color: #2196f3;
}

.base, div {
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this, the error message basically told me what to do:

```
SassError: compound selectors may no longer be extended.
Consider `@extend .form-control, :focus` instead.
```

Using this should work (don't forget necessary imports to bootstrap):

```
.thirdparty.thirdparty-focused {
  @extend .form-control, :focus;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work, I experience the same issue and I did try what it suggest using the comma ,